# FakeItEasy: Simple Fake not being used

Tags: c#, fakeiteasy

I'm trying to use FakeItEasy (version 4.9.1) to create unit tests for some legacy code. I've created two unit tests, one of which works just as expected, and one very similar which doesn't work despite lots of trial and error.

Here's an excerpt from the method that seems impossible to test:

```
public class PosMessageProcessor : IPosMessageProcessor
{
    public void Execute()
    {
        PurchaseOrderRepository repo = new PurchaseOrderRepository();
        ...
        try
        {
            m_PurchaseOrder = GetOrderForProcessing(repo);
            ...
```

And here's my test:

```
[TestMethod]
[TestCategory("POS")]
public void ExecuteTest()
{
    // Arrange
    PurchaseOrder purchaseOrder = GetPurchaseOrder();
    IPosMessageProcessor fakePosMessageProcessor = A.Fake<IPosMessageProcessor>();
    A.CallTo(() => fakePosMessageProcessor.GetOrderForProcessing(A<IPurchaseOrderRepository>.Ignored)).Returns(purchaseOrder);

    // Act
    _posMessageProcessor.Execute();

    // Assert
    A.CallTo(() => fakePosMessageProcessor.GetOrderForProcessing(A<IPurchaseOrderRepository>.Ignored)).MustHaveHappened();
}
```

The `_posMessageProcessor` variable is an instance of the `PosMessageProcessor` class. I want to catch the call to the `GetOrderForProcessing()` method (within the `Execute()` method) and make it return my hard-coded `purchaseOrder` object. But I get another return value (`null`) instead. Why?

The unit test that works tests the `GetOrderForProcessing()` method:

```
[TestMethod]
[TestCategory("POS")]
public void GetOrderForProcessingTest()
{
    // Arrange
    PurchaseOrder purchaseOrder = GetPurchaseOrder();
    IPurchaseOrderRepository fakePurchaseOrderRepository = A.Fake<IPurchaseOrderRepository>();
    A.CallTo(() => fakePurchaseOrderRepository.GetPurchaseOrderByOrderTrackingNumber(A<string>.Ignored)).Returns(purchaseOrder);

    // Act
    PurchaseOrder result = _posMessageProcessor.GetOrderForProcessing(fakePurchaseOrderRepository);

    // Assert
    A.CallTo(() => fakePurchaseOrderRepository.GetPurchaseOrderByOrderTrackingNumber(A<string>.Ignored)).MustHaveHappened();
    Assert.IsNotNull(result);
}
```

In this case, the call to `GetPurchaseOrderByOrderTrackingNumber()` returns my hard-coded object as expected. The two tests are virtually the same, except that the `GetOrderForProcessing()` method takes a parameter while `Execute()` does not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ExecuteTest` is failing because you configure a fake `IPosMessageProcessor` and then call `Execute` on a real `PosMessageProcessor`, `_posMessageProcessor`. `_posMessageProcessor`, being an actual `PosMessageProcessor`, executes its regular code path, calling the actual `Execute`, which will call the actual `GetOrderForProcessing`.

(Note that you can actually delete the `fakePosMessageProcessor` variable and all references to it from your test, and the behaviour will be the same.)

I do not recommend this kind of testing, but in order to fake `GetOrderForProcessing` and still test the actual `Execute` code, you would have to write a test like

```
public void NewExecuteTest()
{
    // Arrange
    PurchaseOrder purchaseOrder = GetPurchaseOrder();

    // Get a fake PosMessageProcessor that falls back to original behaviour for all calls.
    IPosMessageProcessor fakePosMessageProcessor = A.Fake<PosMessageProcessor>(options => options.CallsBaseMethods());

    // Now fake out the GetOrderForProcessing call so we can test Execute.
    A.CallTo(() => fakePosMessageProcessor.GetOrderForProcessing(A<IPurchaseOrderRepository>.Ignored)).Returns(purchaseOrder);

    // Act
    fakePosMessageProcessor.Execute();

    // Assert
    A.CallTo(() => fakePosMessageProcessor.GetOrderForProcessing(A<IPurchaseOrderRepository>.Ignored)).MustHaveHappened();
}
```

Comment: Many thanks for helping out. However, I get a `FakeItEasy.Configuration.FakeConfigurationException` error on the `A.CallTo()` in the arrange section, saying: _Non-virtual members can not be intercepted. Only interface members and virtual, overriding, and abstract members can be intercepted._ This always happens whenever I put a class (not an interface) in `A.Fake<T>()`. Having the ability to fake classes was the big reason for me to leave Rhino. Am I missing some other option?

Comment: That's a problem, then. Only virtual members [can be overridden](https://fakeiteasy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/what-can-be-faked/#what-members-can-be-overridden). This is a standard limitation of frameworks based on DynamicProxy, such as FakeItEasy, Moq, and NSubstitute. I'd see if you could make the method virtual or otherwise change your collaboration model. To my knowledge, if you absolutely require the ability to configure non-virtual members, you need to use a commercial framework such as TypeMock Isolator.

Comment: Thanks again. I learned from your responses. In the end, I was able to intercept a call to a method on `IPurchaseOrderRepository` instead, which made it more straightforward.